# Color box-header when box is rendered from server

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I want to render a box from server side, and want to color its header. I can color its background, but not the box-header background or the box-header font. Also the box refuses to collapse. Code below.

```
        ui <- navbarPage(id="hard", 
                 header = tagList(
                   useShinydashboard()
                 ),
                 title = "Box test",
                 tabPanel("About",
                          uiOutput("box_01"),
                          tags$style("#button_box_01>.box-header { color:yellow; background:red}"),
                          tags$style("#button_box_01 {background:green}")
                 )
      )

        server <- function(input,output,server){
                           output$box_01 <- renderUI({
                                                      box1<-box(title = "Select Input Type", status = 
                                                                "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                                                 collapsible = TRUE, strong("This is an 
                                                                 empty box"))
                           box1$children[[1]]$attribs$class<-"action-button"
                           box1$children[[1]]$attribs$id<-"button_box_01"
                           return(box1)
        })
       }

       shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(title = "Box test",
    tags$head(
      #tags$style("#button_box_01>.box-header { color:yellow; background:red}"),
      tags$style("#button_box_01 {background:orange;
                                  color:red;
                                  font-size: 40px;
                                  font-style: italic;
                                  line-height: .8;
                 }")
    ),
    fluidRow("About", uiOutput("box_01"), plotOutput("plot") )
  )            
)
# style = "color:red"
server <- function(input,output,server){
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(10))
  })
  
  output$box_01 <- renderUI({
    box1 <- box(title = "Select Input Type", 
                status = "primary", 
                solidHeader = TRUE, 
                collapsible = TRUE, 
                collapsed = TRUE,
                strong("This is an empty box"))
    # box1$children[[1]]$attribs$class<-"action-button"
    box1$children[[1]]$attribs$id<-"button_box_01"
    return(box1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: I wanted to know how to change the blue color on the box header to say pink. I do not want to use a the set of standard colors as allowed in status option of box.

Comment: Status option has the color selection. Further selection can be done via your own javascript or CSS file.  I don't know that.